# The number of comparisons in brute force string search

Tags: algorithms, searching

In the brute force approach to string search, how many character comparisons will the algorithm make when searching for "lido" in the string "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"?

Comment: I would say 33...

Comment: How did you calculate the result?

Comment: First put "lido" under the "s" : one comparison, shift right. "lido" under "u", one comparison, shift right... When "lido" gets under "lifragili", 3 comparisons, $f\ne d$, shift right... Until "lido" under "lidocious", four comparisons, we have a winner...

Comment: 7+3(lif)+5+3(lis)+9+4(lido)+2=33
In this case, the algorithm jumps over "if" in "lif" , "is" in "lis" and "ido" in "lido". Am I right?